# mysqli_query don't work in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to make an easy Select from the db and save the results in an array.

```
            $query = "SELECT ID FROM Publikationen WHERE Personen LIKE '%; " . $autor2 . "%';";
            echo($query);
            // get IDs
            $res = mysqli_query($link,$query );
            $i = 0;
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
                echo($row['ID']);
                $IDarray[$i]= $row['ID'];           
                $i++;
            }
```

The `$autor2` variable is an Name like: "Doe, John".
The code seems to not go in the loop, and `mysqli_error` after the loop is null so it seems im not getting results from the db.
When im copying the echo from `$query` in phpMyAdmin it works fine. Also when im using a Name instead `$autor2` it also works fine and im getting my whole Array.

Comment: Why you are add additional `;` in your query? You need to correct your query to `$query = "SELECT ID FROM Publikationen WHERE Personen LIKE '%$autor2%'";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see in the SQL query, there's a syntax error.

You wrote :

```
SELECT ID FROM Publikationen WHERE Personen LIKE '%; " . $autor2 . "%';
```

but it should have been :

```
SELECT ID FROM Publikationen WHERE Personen LIKE '%" . $autor2 . "%';
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The semicolon is necessary cause i want to get all db entries where the searched name is not on the first position and they are seperated by the ";"

Comment: ok i did it with an "_" instead the semicolon, it works too in my case

Comment: Great then! I'm glad you got your way ;)

Comment: @BennyMüller the `;` is an "end of statement" character and it just "halts" your script.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT ID FROM Publikationen WHERE Personen LIKE '%" . $autor2 . "%'";
```

write this code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `semicolon` from the query.

```
$query = "SELECT ID FROM Publikationen WHERE Personen LIKE '% " . $autor2 . "%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this -

```
$query = "SELECT ID FROM Publikationen WHERE Personen LIKE '%$autor2%'";
```

If the semicolon is important then use it but use the $author2 variable just inside single quote (' ').